# Elasticsearch return extract of query

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i'm new on elasticsearch and for now i indexed a website and i would like to get a text extract with the word(s) of my query,

Example I index

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec
>   odio in magna blandit porta quis a nibh. Integer sodales ex ut
>   sagittis venenatis. Duis efficitur ligula ac magna tincidunt, in
>   iaculis magna facilisis. **Nullam pulvinar** diam vitae elit auctor auctor
>   a a urna. Fusce accumsan non magna non fermentum. Curabitur dapibus
>   tempus nisi, efficitur mattis magna aliquam nec. In hac habitasse
>   platea dictumst. In lacus nulla, feugiat vitae neque ac, aliquam
>   hendrerit orci.

If i request Nullam pulvinar i would like to get an extract like

> **Nullam pulvinar** diam vitae elit auctor auctor a a urna.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) for this purpose.
From the Docs

```
{
    "query" : {...},
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

You can also specify `fragment_size` and `number_of_fragments` depending on your requirements.